# How to increase brightness of web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

is anyone knows how to increase page brightness or make the web page with shinier colors? I used white (#fff) as background-color but some websites look shinier than my one. My page background color looks dull. can I use CSS for that or any other libraries for that?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type on screen settings and quality too, what you are using for the display. However assuming that you are using you are using the same display yo view both the pages (ie. your page and reference page). You can use the Background filter function to adjust the brightness of the highlighted section or even the compete page. you may also play around the contrast and saturation too to have a more vibrant combination. The function for brightness is  `brightness([Value in percent]);`

For example

`.brighter{
  filter: brightness(200%);
}`

For details you may refer to the following MDN link [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness)

Comment: I already checked this one, it increases the image brightness, not the whole page.

Comment: This works on the complete page too but the change in the brightness would be visible only on the coloured content, as white is itself the Max brightness colour, Hence you would have to play around the colour pallet too.

Comment: you can also set body { filter: contrast(200%)}